# blank pages between subsections in appendix

Tags: appendix

I have used

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell,
tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}\spacing{1.5}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber, natbib, style=trad-abbrv, maxbibnames=5, minbibnames=5, giveninits=true,
    style=apa
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}

\graphicspath{ {./Graphs/} }

\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{\hfill Source: {#1}} }



\begin{document}


\appendix

\section{}
\subsection{}\label{A}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l} 
\hline
  Good & Variable & Content \\
  \hline
 Beef & \thead[l]{EF88 \\ EF89 \\ EF90\\ EF91} & \thead[l]{Beef to cook \\ Beef to braise and roast \\ Veal \\ Other beef incl. ground meat} \\ 
 \hline
 Pork & \thead[l]{EF92 \\ EF100 \\ EF101 \\ EF102 \\ EF103 \\ EF104} & \thead[l]{Pork incl. ground meat \\ Dried, salted, smoked and sausage products  \\ Sausages to grill \\ Sausages to cook \\ Canned sausages \\ Other sausages} \\
 \hline
 Poultry & \thead[l]{EF94 \\ EF95 \\ EF96 \\ EF97} & \thead[l]{Chicken\\ Duck \\ Turkey \\ Other poultry }\\ 
 \hline
 Cheese & \thead[l]{EF128 \\ EF129 \\ EF130 \\ EF131 \\ EF132 \\ EF133 \\ EF135} & \thead[l]{Hard cheese \\ Semi-hard cheese \\ Soft cheese \\ Sour milk cheese \\ Cheese spread \\ Cream cheese \\ Other cheese}  \\ 
 \hline
 Butter & EF145 &  \\ 
 \hline
 Milk & EF144 &  \\ 
 \hline
 Yoghurt & EF127 &  \\ 
 \hline
 Cream & EF136 &  \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\caption{Overview of variable construction}
\end{table}

\subsection{}\label{B}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Engel/1/Engel_w.png}
    \caption{First stage budget share Engel curves}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Engel/m/Engel_w2m.png}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Engel/d/Engel_w2d.png}
    \caption{Second stage budget share Engel curves}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Engel/1/Engel_q.png}
    \caption{First stage quantity Engel curves}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Engel/m/Engel_q2m.png}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Engel/d/Engel_q2d.png}
    \caption{Second stage quantity Engel curves}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Engel/1/Engel_lnq.png}
    \caption{First stage log(quantity) Engel curves}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Engel/m/Engel_lnq2m.png}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Engel/d/Engel_lnq2d.png}
    \caption{Second stage log(quantity) Engel curves}
\end{figure}


\subsection{}\label{C}


\begin{table}[H]
   \centering
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
   \sisetup{table-format=-1.3{***}}
            
   \begin{tabular}{l *{6}{S}}
       \hline
       \hline
       \multicolumn{7}{c}{Price} \\
       \hline
        & {Meat} & {Dairy} & {Vegetables} & {Fruits} & {\thead[l]{Potatoes \\ Pasta \\ Rice}} & {\thead[l]{Bread \\ Oats}}  \\
          \hline
          \hline
Meat    & -1.017*** &  0.044*** & -0.090*** & -0.140*** & -0.049*** & -0.165***     \\
Dairy   &  0.097*** & -1.009*** & -0.044*** & -0.009    &  0.030*** & -0.021**      \\
Fruits  &  0.000    & -0.044*** & -0.688*** &  0.006    & -0.039*** &  0.020        \\
Vegetables 
        & -0.089*** &  0.057*** &  0.025*   & -0.673*** & -0.001    &  0.009        \\
\thead[l]{Potatoes \\ Pasta \\ Rice}   
        & -0.194*** & -0.046**  & -0.016    & -0.073*** & -0.780*** & -0.043*       \\
\thead[l]{Bread \\ Oats}   
        &  0.003    & -0.099*** & -0.118*** & -0.047**  &  0.010    & -0.496***     \\
    \hline
    \hline
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\footnotesize  * p$<$0.1, ** p$<$0.05, *** p$<$0.01}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{First stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities}
\label{cross_price_1}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
       \centering
       \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
        \sisetup{table-format=-1.3{***}}
      \begin{tabular}{l *{3}{S}}
       \hline
       \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{Price} \\
       \hline
          & {Beef} & {Pork} & {Poultry}  \\
          \hline
          \hline
          Beef & -0.494***   &  -0.516***  & -0.228***   \\
          
          Pork & -0.048***   &  -0.903***   &  0.008  \\
          
          Poultry  &   -0.209***  &   -0.082**  &  -0.822***  \\
          \hline
          \hline
           \multicolumn{4}{c}{\footnotesize  * p$<$0.1, ** p$<$0.05, *** p$<$0.01}
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{Second stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities}
       \label{cross_price_2m}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
           \centering
           \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
           \sisetup{table-format=-1.3{***}}
      \begin{tabular}{l *{5}{S}}
           \hline
           \hline
            \multicolumn{6}{c}{Price} \\
           \hline
              & {Cheese} & {Butter} & {Milk} & {Yoghurt} & {Cream} \\
              \hline
              \hline
              Cheese & -0.847*** & 0.002 & -0.068*** & -0.066*** & -0.031** \\

              Butter & 0.017 & -0.996*** & 0.007 & 0.008 & -0.028\\

              Milk & -0.224*** & 0.002 & -0.846*** & 0.029 & 0.016 \\

              Yoghurt & -0.208*** & 0.018 & 0.052 & -0.748*** & -0.033 \\

              Cream & -0.289*** & -0.072 & 0.039 & -0.091*** & -0.631*** \\
              \hline
              \hline
               \multicolumn{6}{c}{\footnotesize * p$<$0.1, ** p$<$0.05, *** p$<$0.01}
           \end{tabular}
           \caption{Second stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities}
           \label{cross_price_2d}
    \end{table}

\subsection{}\label{D}

\begin{figure}[H] 
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Tax/abs_tax_low.png}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphs/Tax/tax_low.png}
    \caption{Absolute and relative carbon taxes based on a carbon price of 30\euro/tCO$_2$} \label{taxes_low}
\end{figure}

\subsection{}\label{E}

\begin{table}[H]
       \centering
       \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
       \begin{tabular}[width=\textwidth]{c c c}
       \hline
       \hline
           Income quintile & Upper interval boundary & Within-quintile mean \\
          \hline
          \hline
          1 &  $<$ 17.552\euro & 12.980\euro\\
          \hline
          2 &  $<$ 24.795\euro &  21.292\euro\\
          \hline
          3 &  $<$ 32.216\euro & 28.374\euro\\
          \hline
          4 &  $<$ 42.539\euro &  36.910\euro\\
          \hline
          5  & $<$ 715.588\euro & 60.591\euro\\
          \hline
          \hline
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{Annual household net income quintile description}
       \label{quint}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

to generate my Appendix. I use for graphs etc. of every section of the paper a different subsection in the appendix. However, in my table of contents this looks as follows:
[image]

Yet, I would like it to say Appendix instead of A. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Also for some reason I have a blank page between two subsections of the appendix. There is no need for leaving a whole extra blank page before the bar charts. How could I solve this?

Sorry if this has gotten a little long, but I hope this brings across my issue. Frankly, I am just a starter in Latex.

Comment: What document class are you using?  That's what defines such things.  If you can provide a small compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document} that demontrates what is happening, it should be possible to determine the cause without guessing.

Comment: I have edited it as you suggested. Any thoughts? :)

Comment: All you show is the preamble, not how the affected parts are actually input.  Without that evidence, nobody can do anything but guess.  To make a usable example, copy your main file under another name, remove anything that doesn't demonstrate your problem, check to make sure that the stripped-down example *does* in fact demonstrate the problem, and post that.

Comment: is that better now?

Comment: Sadly, you still haven't shown the input that produces your output.  We need to see what's between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, but only the parts that cause the problem.

Comment: In addition to what Barbara said, notice (1) you don't have a `\tableofcontents` command but mentioned a ToC, (2) you use images and a bibliography we don't have access to and so cannot compile your document; that stuff should be removed or replaced with something like `example-image-a` from the graphicx package, (3) nothing in what you posted defines `\euro` to my knowledge so the code won't compile anyway. See the info on how to create a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).